# String sorting problem NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sorting, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have set a string (which is in fact a string) as the sectionNameKeyPath. It's sorts fine, but for example 16 september 2011, is in an earlier section than 2 september 2011. What is the best way to work around this problem

[image]

**Update** My workaround is instead of a string, make an int from it (e.g. 20110909 for 2011-09-09) and then later in titleForHeader method turn it in a string again

Comment: This is because 3 > 1...

Comment: It doesn't sort fine at all. Just as an example, "1 November 2011" will also come after "1 December 2011".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because as in any other language, this is sorted as an String and the first character 3 is bigger than 1. You will have to implement your own comparator if you want them to sort any other way.

Answer (score 0):

I advise to convert `NSString` back to `NSDate` and use standard `[NSDate compare:]` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your NSStrings to NSDates and then sort them, something like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"d MMM yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"3 September 2011"];
```